# How do I create a console application in C++?

Tags: c++

I wanna make a application like this:

this is console for example:

```
write_number 5
Your number is 5
```

How do that?

Can someone explain ?

Comment: In the future, please try to use google to solve your problem before trying to use stack overflow.  Then let us know what you tried to look up.  That way, you're not wasting our time, and you're actually learning something, rather than having someone hand solutions to you.

Comment: Err Merlyn, that's not actually the point of this site...

Comment: @Mark: This isn't a dictation of the rules, it is a suggestion for how they can improve their learning process, improve the interest people take in answering their questions, and improve the quality of answers they receive.

Comment: This question is unanswerable unless you include the OS and compiler you're using.  It might also help to define "console" further, since two lines of text aren't exactly a console.  If you used command prompts, it would at least show what interaction you wanted.

Comment: @Merlyn:  I don't mind explaining the dead obvious stuff.  One of the SO goals is that the Google references will be to SO.  On the other hand, I dislike having to work to get a coherent elementary question from somebody.

Comment: @Mark, David: Maybe you're right, that my recommendation doesn't align to SO goals (namely, "build good answers to every imaginable programming question").  However, I hypothesize that people who learn how to solve their own low-hanging problems today will ask more interesting questions in the future.

Answer (score 9):

If you're hoping to learn programming by asking questions on Stack Overflow, you're going to be at it for a long time.  I would recommend getting [Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/programming.html) or [Accelerated C++](http://www.acceleratedcpp.com/).

As to your question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "your number is " << std::atoi(argv[1]) << '\n';
}
```

Please note this is not the best version of this program (eg., what if the user doesn't pass an argument, or doesn't pass a number as an argument, or passes a number larger than an `int`, or passes a number that is a `float` or `double` instead of an `int`?), but it does give you an idea.

More advanced topics -- without buying the books -- can be found at [Bjarne Stroustrup's technical FAQ](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#simple-program) (Stroustrup created the original versions of C++).

Comment: +1. Oh, he actually meant to retrieve values via parameters, not console input.  Perceptive!

Comment: The original formatting didn't make that very obvious.

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question asked.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a basic tutorial on cin and cout ("see-in/out")

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/

Answer (score 4):

Use console input and output.  These are exposed most simply in C++ by std::cin and std::cout:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int value;
  std::cout << "write_number ";
  std::cin >> value;
  std::cout << "Your number is " << value << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

For how *best* to use these features, check out this FAQ:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html

**Edit**

If you're trying to get **command line arguments** to your program, such that your session looks like this:

> C:\Users\MyUserName> my_program 5
>   Your number is 5

Then you use the arguments passed to the `main` function.  This is an array of all the parameters you passed to the program when you ran it:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Your number is " << argv[1] << "\n";
}
```

The arguments passed in are in string (textual) form, though.  If you want to convert them to a number, so that you can do arithmatic or perform comparisons with them, here is a way to do that:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.2

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

class BadConversion : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
  BadConversion(std::string const& s)
    : std::runtime_error(s)
  { }
};

template<typename T>
T ConvertTo(std::string const& s)
{
  std::istringstream i(s);
  T x;
  if (!(i >> x))
    throw BadConversion("convertTo(\"" + s + "\")");
  return x;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int first_parameter = ConvertTo<int>(argv[1]);
  std::cout << "Your number is " << first_parameter << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are interacting with the user you should force the output buffer to flush before trying to get input. This is easily done with std::endl

Comment: `cin` and `cout` are tied by default (flushing happens automatically where you need it):  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/tie/ .

Comment: @Martin, Max: Didn't know that Max.  Will revert it back

Comment: it's a good detail to know (both that things need to be flushed and that `cin` and `cout` do the flushing automatically).  It does come up once in a while ( http://blog.think-async.com/2007/01/unbuffered-socket-iostreams.html ).

Answer (score 2):

How about we step through this.

First, we want to ask the user for input, how would we go about doing this?

```
// TODO: Ask user for input.
```

Once we have that input, how would we go about constructing the new string?

```
// TODO: Make new string.
```

Now that we have the new string, how do we display it to the user?

```
// TODO: Display the string.
```

This leaves use with the following skeleton for you to fill out:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    // TODO: Ask user for input.
    // TODO: Make new string.
    // TODO: Display the string.
    return 0;
}
```

To accomplish this, you could use `cout`, `cin`, and `string`. (Of course you could do the string formatting directly in cout as well)

Answer (score 0):

```
int num = 0;
printf("write_number ");
cin >> num;
cout << "Your number is " << num;
```

Comment: printf and cout in the same code'?

Comment: That may have problems.  `cin` and `cout` are synchronized, but I don't think they synchronize with `printf`.  The "write_number" could appear before or after the read from `cin` and/or the write from `cout`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int number = 5;
cout << "Your number" << number;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to do something a little more interactive, but still want to work in the console, look into [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)).